# Loading a Web Page Directly from a JavaScript File Exclusively

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I have the desire to do something that I've never seen done.

I'd like to create a web page **using only client-side javascript**. For example, I want to put a javascript file at www.webpage.com/index.js and have the browser run that javascript file. Within that file, I'll generate html and css, but I'd like the entry point to be exclusively that javascript file instead of HTML.

If this is not possible, I think it should be. Many times my html files are just a header, title and an empty body. When this is the case, it is silly that an html file has to be downloaded first, and then only after that can the browser download the javascript file that actually fills that empty body with content.

I realize that search engines may not know how to index pages where the html is generated by client-side javascript, but again, I say they should be able to do this and probably eventually will if they haven't already.

I've never seen this done. Is this possible? If so, can you please direct me to any resources covering the topic. I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Not possible, unless you want to do something like instruct the user to open up their browser console and copy-paste in the code

Comment: I predict that one day, this will be part of the standard. It saves an extra trip to the server.

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said it is not possible to run a standalone js file in the browser (without extensions or additional user input) . To minimise html requests and only download a single file you could use a build system to insert all your javascript between script tags in a html stub, but this would mean you wouldn't benefit from browser caching.

Comment: Further discussion on this can be found [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/807).

Comment: Should the `document` object be available by default for the script, as it rightfully is with a traditional HTML document that typically contains the script? If that's the case, what *kind of document* would that be? There isn't a one-to-one relationship between a script and a document most people like to script. You can have SVG documents, for instance, that run scripts? I mean, if we'd agree on some convention or outright not define any `window.document` for such "bare-bones" scripts, it could work. But as it stands, for now you'll have to provide a document first.

Comment: @amn: I'm ok with using [document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) to create the document myself (without using an html *file*). However, I just realized that not even that is available without some type of base document. So, yeah, we'd need what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned elsewhere](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/807#issuecomment-488326500), it's possible to create JavaScript that is also a valid HTML file.

```
<!-- --><script>
console.log('Hello, World!');
// </script>
```

This works because [the JavaScript spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-html-like-comments) has

> ## B Additional ECMAScript Features for Web Browsers
>
> ### B.1 Additional Syntax
>
> #### B.1.3 HTML-like Comments
>
> ...
>
> *SingleLineHTMLOpenComment* ::
>       `<!--` *SingleLineCommentChars*<sub>opt</sub>

Comment: That's poor design -- `<!--` and its counterpart `-->` are used with XML documents, and unless I have forgotten about some part of some spec which says that whenever a user agent encounters `<!--` it should assume it's a valid HTML (as opposed to XML) document, we have ambiguity on our hands -- a user agent may rightfully interpret your quoted snippet as a `application/xml` resource (if no `Content-Type` is provided through HTTP or an equivalent `meta` element).

Comment: And that *only* in cases where no content type is provided. If content type is provided, assuming the above snippet is an HTML document just looks outright like a bug to me. If origin says `text/javascript` then that's a script, and no amount of well-parsing XML/HTML-like comments is going to fix that, regardless whether these comments are valid in context of JavaScript script files, or not.

Comment: @amn Yes, you should always specify a content type header.

If you want the page to be treated as interactive content, serve it with a text/html content-type.

It's easy to resolve any XML/HTML ambiguity.  The HTML spec allows comment tokens before `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: This doesn't meet my "using only client-side javascript" criterion because this solution requires an HTML wrapper. However, when something is impossible, the best you can do is come up with the closest alternative. You've done that in clever fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I've written many "pages" that are just

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
   <body><script>

// The real stuff goes here, as inlined Javascript
// No need to make an extra roundtrip to the server
let d = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
d.textContent = "Hello, world.";

   </body></script>
</html>
```

So basically the only thing I place in the HTML part is a fix for a bad decision taken in the past (having the default encoding ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8).
This kind of file is indeed just Javascript, with the minimal wrapping needed to have a browser loading and executing it.

Comment: Exactly, the standards should offer a way to skip the middleman: HTML. A client-side javascript file, that generates html, should be just as valid an entry point as an html file in 2019.

Comment: @LonnieBest: the "overhead" is indeed minimal and there is no "extra trip to the server"; the browser loads and executes the code. Adding yet another strange rule and consequent browser incompatibility to the already embarrassingly complex set of rules for such a little gain wouldn't be worth in my opinion.

Comment: I can't see the complexity outweighing the benefit here, because to me it seems very simple to permit javascript as an entry point to a web page. The engines already know how to run javascript, so the fact that the HTML page is generated (instead of a static file) should be transparent after that generation has occurred. Not much is changing, except the source of the html. We do the same thing server-side all the time. And saving that trip to the server is not the only benefit. I hate creating those empty html files and I'd love to be able to accomplish the same thing without leaving my JS.

Comment: @LonnieBest: In my example the Javascript is INSIDE the page... the HTML file is not empty, it contains the code as inlined Javascript. The only "problem" is that the meat of the file (the javascript code) is wrapped in a tiny foil of HTML. No extra trip to the server. Changing the browsers standard so that a specially crafted reply from the server should be run directly by the browser instead of the current handling would be a little gain. Note also that you don't want to lose the ability of actually downloading a Javascript file instead of executing it.

Comment: You don't have to explain your example to me, I've used the same technique many times. Don't confuse my advocating of "the way I'd like things to be" as an argument against your example. I get it. I started making webpages in 1995. I want to be able to accomplish the same thing using javascript exclusively; the only "wrapper" I want is where javascript is doing the wrapping. I want the HTML to be inside a js template string surround by javascript! I'm promoting that a client-side javascript file should be a supported entry point to a website/webpage. Also, view-source would still be possible.